# Django extra registration details not saving

Tags: python, django

I have form.py with class RegistrationForm and everything works fine but the extra details like email, first and last name, roles is not saved to my account/User profiles but first and last name + emails is saved under AUTHENTICATION AND AUTHORIZATION/Users

I been trying to figure our if I made some mix up with model, form or views.

What could be the problem? Using python 3 with latest django

[image]

2nd

[image]

3rd

[image]

Models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
STUDENT = 1
TOURIST = 2
BUSINESS = 3
ADMIN = 4
ROLE_CHOICES = (
    (STUDENT, 'Student'),
    (TOURIST, 'Tourist'),
    (BUSINESS, 'Business'),
    (ADMIN, 'Admin'),
)
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
# first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
# last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
email = models.EmailField()
phone = models.IntegerField(default=0)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image_profile', blank=True)
role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)

# admin = UserProfileManager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username


def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

forms.py

```
ROLES = ((0, 'Student'), (1, 'Tourist'), (2, 'Business'))


class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    role = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ROLES)
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = (
        'username',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'role',
        'password1',
        'password2'
    )

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    user.role = self.cleaned_data['role']
    user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

    if commit:
        user.save()

    return user
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Your account has been created!')
        return redirect(reverse('city:home'))
else:
    form = RegistrationForm()

    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'account/register_form.html', args)
```

Admin.py

```
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('user', 'role', 'email')

def user_info(self, obj):
    return obj.role

def get_queryset(self, request):
    queryset = super(UserProfileAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    queryset = queryset.order_by('email')
    return queryset

    role.short_description = 'User Type'
```

admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileAdmin)

Comment: Show us the code, that will help to understand what actually you have tried.

Comment: model forms and views (admin.py if you have one too) please.

Comment: I have updated the codes

Answer (score 1):

By given screen shots i think you are using allauth library. If you want to use allauth and modify user model then you have to import AbstractUser class of allauth

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
      phone = models.CharField(_('Telephone'), blank=True, max_length=20)
      address = models.CharField(_('Address'), blank=True, max_length=255)
```